# Why tor-request dont't update ip in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, tor

I have following code:

```
var tr = require('tor-request');
tr.TorControlPort.password = '***'

tr.request('https://api.ipify.org', (err, resp, ip) => {
    console.log('initial ip: ' + ip)
})

function torRequest() {
    tr.renewTorSession((err, msg) => {
        console.log(msg);
        tr.request('https://api.ipify.org', (err, resp, ip) => {
            console.log('ip: ' + ip)
        })
    })
}

torRequest();

for ( let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    torRequest();
}
```

And my output:

```
Tor session successfully renewed!!
Tor session successfully renewed!!
Tor session successfully renewed!!
ip: 46.165.245.154
ip: 46.165.245.154
ip: 46.165.245.154
initial ip: 176.10.107.180
```

When I call `torRequest` more than once, all requests will return with the same ip. Is it possible to run it in the loop?

Comment: Maybe you should check the `err` argument. You might have an error, for example if there is a limit to how many times you can renew your IP in a given amount of time.

Comment: I did, there was no errors

Comment: What does `msg` contains ?

Comment: I updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly refresh the tor's session

```
tr.newTorSession( (err) =>
{
    requestIP();
    return;
});
```

Also add this

```
tr.setTorAddress('localhost', 9050);
```

after

```
tr.TorControlPort.password = '***'
```

newTorSessio :

```
module.exports = {
// <snip>

  /**
   * Helper object to communicate with the tor ControlPort. Requires an enabled ControlPort on tor.
   */
  TorControlPort: {
    password: "", // default ControlPort password
    host: "localhost", // default address
    port: 9051, // default ControlPort
    
    /**
     * @param {Array.string} commands - signals that are sent to the ControlPort
     */
    send: function (commands, done(err, data))
  }
  
  /**
   * A set of predefined TorControlPort commands to request and verify tor for a new session (get a new ip to use).
   *
   * @param {function} done - the callback function to tell you when the process is done
   * @param {object} err - null if tor session renewed successfully
   */
  newTorSession: function ( done(err) ) // clears and renews the Tor session (i.e., you get a new IP)
  

}
```

that's it .. it will work.. in my case .. IP will be updated after 5-6 times

Good luck,'.